# Flutter - How to build a multi image picker with preview on the same page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to build a multi-image picker in flutter where it is possible to access the gallery images, select multiple and also preview the last one tapped, all on the same screen.

Any ideas? Is there a way to access the phone gallery besides using the image_picker package?

thanks

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is sample video for making gallery https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfA3koMnhvM like instagram

but its only works for android.

https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker this package works both android and ios. Refer this package to make your own.